# ruby find_by_sql string parameters converting int parameter into string throws error in limit mysql 8

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a ruby on rails Rails 7.0.2.2 webapp (ruby version 3.0.3) with a query to mysql 8.0.18 for macos10.14 on x86_64 database like:

```
pagIndex = params[:pagIndex].to_i
limitBoats = 20
offset = pagIndex * 20  
values = Array.new  
indexValues = 0

sQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT b.id, ... FROM ... WHERE ... LIMIT ? OFFSET ?"

values.insert(indexValues + 1, limitBoats)
values.insert(indexValues + 2, offset)    
values.shift    
values.insert(0, sQuery)
@result = Entity.find_by_sql(values)
```

This code is working perfectly and it´s translating to a query like:

```
SELECT ... LIMIT '20' OFFSET '0';
```

where limit and offset are strings.

This has been working perfectly for years in my previous ruby 2.4, rails 4 and mysql 5.5. However, after migrating to ruby 3, Rails 7 and mysql 8, I get error in the limit and offset parameters, because mysql is expecting an integer.

If I just remove the '', the query works. How can I get this working with find_by_sql?

I guess I´m missing something as I don´t even find any other issues like this one.

Note: limit and offset are part of a pagination, so they are coming from variables and I cannot just use these values as constant integers.

**UPDATE**
According to @muistooshort comment, just to debug it easier, if I just create a method with:

```
@result = Entity.find_by_sql(['select * from entity limit ?', 11])
    logger.debug "Entities=" + @result.inspect
```

I´m getting this output:

```
DEBUG -- :   Entity Load (0.5ms)  select * from boats limit '11'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms | Allocations: 324)


  
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''11'' at line 1):
```

As you can see it´s changing the int to string and mysql 8 complains.

Comment: They are variables. I think they can be whatever, I´d say initially strings because they are coming from get parameters, but I try to convert them to integer with values.insert(indexValues + 1, limitBoats.to_i) but nothing change. I mean, the prepared sql shows like string with ''.

Comment: I have updated the description. As you can see limitBoats it´s initialised as a number

Comment: I have updated the description with a simple test. I guess I´m missing something because I cannot understand this is happening only to me.

Comment: Why don't you use the ActiveRecord query language in the first place?

Comment: The query on the description, is just a small one, for debugging purposes. The real query is complex and dinamically generated according to many parameters.

Comment: Bug has been reported:  https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=103437  Subscribe to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally strange to me, but I created next bug in Rails:
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/44853

and they answered they needed to do this on purpose, so now the only way to send a query using find_by_sql with limit is with a workaround defined here:
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/44312

Comment: Nicely done tracking it down like that. Shame that MySQL tries to be "friendly" like that though.